# Archive linked entities in other tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I want to archive some of my entities as other entities. For example : a Colle entity as to become a BanqueColle entity. These entities don't have exactly the same fields. Thing is I can't use Doctrine ORM because I have a table with 1M records in it.

I succeeded in doing that with some SQL queries. But to do so, I had to keep the Ids from the initial table to keep all the links between these entities.

I just thought about a problem : next time I'll archive my entities, I'll have some Ids already in archived table. How can I get past that ?

Or do you have a more elegant way to archive my entities than keeping all Ids ?

Comment: "Thing is I can't use Doctrine ORM because I have a table with 1M records in it." - how does the size of the table have anything to do with whether or not you can use Doctrine ORM?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you need. Why would you even need to move your entities into another table?

Comment: I can't use Doctrine because of the time needed to transfert every entity.

I need to move my entities to another table to use them in another part of my project. These new entities doesn't have the same fields as initial entities and that's the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you should have Entities that can be mutated to "archived" status, or you have other entities, that might be created from your former entities, for example, accepting Colle entity in constructor and saving and formatting its data.

These new archived entities might as well store IDs of Colle entities.

Comment: I never thought of using a boolean to set archive status. I made a lot of changes to my code to use the base entities and it's now working and I'll not have problems to archive my entities anymore. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @KristenJoseph-Delaffon this technique is called soft-delete.